# new passport and US visa in old passport has different spelling in middle name

Tags: visas, usa, passports

my husbands new passport has a  corrected middle name of ESPAÑA while his US visa that is in his old passport has a spelling of ESPANA. does he need to secure a new US visa? pls help! thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is not a typo and does not invalidate the visa.

The US does not use special characters (those other than A-Z) for names in their visas. They have their own scheme for translating special characters into non-special ones which typically involves removing the special parts of characters, such as the snake above the "N" in this name.

As a reference, you can see this in the US visa FAQ for Germany (https://de.usembassy.gov/visas/visa-faqs/) in point 1. I could not find a similar FAQ entry on the respective page for Spain, but the same rules should apply.